# jQuery Datatables: export filter on rows and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, export-to-excel, tabletools

I am trying to export only visible columns and filtered columns to csv.

I am using

```
{"sExtends": "xls", "mColumns":"visible", 
"oSelectorOpts": { "filter": "applied", "order":"current"}
}
```

but hidden columns are still on export.

When I remove `oSelectorOpts`, I can see only visible columns on export. Perhaps `mColumns` and `oSelectorOpts` are conflicting?

Answer (score 0):

As per your above mentioned options are correct and there should not arise any conflict too because oSelectorOpt mainly acts on rows and mColumns works over columns. So their operational fields are different. Might be there is something else which is conflicting or is having mistake. If possible share the url where the data-table is used and export is having issue.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to solve this problem myself.
I added `sCharSet` to `utf16le` and sFileName, then it was showing correct export result.